# A basis for a quotient space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, quotient-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of all real-valued polynomials in a fixed variable $t$. Let $\textbf{p}$ be a fixed polynomial of degree $n$, and let $W$ be all polynomials divisible by $\textbf{p}$.

What is a basis for the quotient space $V/W$?
My guess would be that a basis for $V/W$ is $\{[1], [t], [t^2], \dotsc, [t^{n-1}]\}$.

I understand the elements of $V/W$ are equivalence classes of the form
$$[\textbf{q}] = \{\textbf{x} \in V | \textbf{x} - \textbf{q} \in W\}.$$

This means that $\textbf{x} - \textbf{q} = \textbf{p}\textbf{y}$ for some polynomial $\textbf{y}$. I do notice that $\textbf{q}$ is a remainder term, and $\operatorname{deg}(\textbf{q}) < \operatorname{deg}(\textbf{p})$. But I still don't see how I can determine a basis for $V/W$. If anyone can help me that would be great!

Comment: The degree of the remainder ought to be strictly less than the degree of $p$. So you may want to delete $[t^n]$ from your guess.

Comment: Ah yes, I will do that!

Comment: So you can now see that these elements span $V/W$?

Comment: And that they are LI?

Comment: To be honest, no. I just don't see it how  they are connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spanning** Let $f\in V$, then $f(t)=q(t)p(t)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i t^i$. So $[f(t)]=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i [t^i]$.

**Linear Independence** Suppose some $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i [t^i]=[0]$. Then $[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i t^i]=[0]$. That means $p(t)$, a polynomial of degree $n$, divides a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i t^i$ of degree at most $n-1$. That can only happen if we have that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i t^i$ is the zero polynomial, and so all $b_i=0$.